# Zlib with using Win api createFile and ReadFile

Tags: zlib

I saw 'zlib Usage Example' at the www.zlib.net but they used 'fread' function from stdio.h.

I have to consider the performance of my program so I must use win api 'ReadFile' function.

But I saw this too.

```
This is an ugly hack required to avoid corruption of the input and output data on
Windows/MS-DOS systems. Without this, those systems would assume that the input and
output files are text, and try to convert the end-of-line characters from one standard 
to another. That would corrupt binary data, and in particular would render the 
compressed data unusable. This sets the input and output to binary which suppresses the 
end-of-line conversions. SET_BINARY_MODE() will be used later on stdin and stdout, at 
the beginning of main().

#if defined(MSDOS) || defined(OS2) || defined(WIN32) || defined(__CYGWIN__)
#  include <fcntl.h>
#  include <io.h>
#  define SET_BINARY_MODE(file) setmode(fileno(file), O_BINARY)
#else
#  define SET_BINARY_MODE(file)
#endif
```

What should I do too use ReadFile on zlib?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nothing.  ReadFile reads binary.